# Connecting client to server in Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, server, client

I'm trying to connect my client to server on a remote server. We were told any port number over 8 thousand is allowed so I assume that's not the problem. However, I get ERROR Connection timed out when trying to connect. Everything I have read seems to say the port is a problem.

Client.c

```
char sendbuff[1024];
char getbuff[1024];
int newsocket = 0;
int prt       = 9345;
//struct hostent *server;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *hp;
    if( ( newsocket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0 ) ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "ERROR: can't create socket" );
    }
    char *hostname = argv[1];

    hp = gethostbyname( hostname );
    memcpy( ( void* )&serv_addr.sin_addr, hp->h_addr_list[0], hp->h_length );
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port   = htons(prt);

    while( connect( newsocket,( struct sockaddr*  )&serv_addr, sizeof( serv_addr ) ) < 0 )
    {
        perror( "ERROR%" );
        sleep( 3 );
    }
    memset( getbuff,'\0',sizeof ( getbuff ) );
    recv( newsocket, getbuff, sizeof( getbuff ), 0 );
    printf( "test%s\n",getbuff );
    return 0;
}
```

Server.C

```
char sendbuff[1024];
char getbuff[1024];
int prt = 9345;
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    printf( "server testing\n" );
    bank = newBank();

    pthread_t listenforclients; /* listen for clients*/
    if( pthread_create( &listenforclients, 0, listenforclients_thread, 0 ) != 0 )
    {
        printf("error\n");
    }
    pthread_join(listenforclients,NULL);
    return 0;
}

void* listenforclients_thread( void* arg )
{
    char buffer[1025];
    int listening=0;
    int accepted=0;
    listening=socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    memset( &serv_addr, '0', sizeof( serv_addr ) );
    memset( buffer,'\0', sizeof buffer ) );

    serv_addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY );
    serv_addr.sin_port        = htons( prt );
    printf( "test before bind\n" );
    bind( listening, ( struct sockaddr* )&serv_addr,  sizeof( serv_addr ) );


    if( listen( listening, 10 ) == -1 )
    {
        printf("ERROR:listen errpr\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    while ( 1 )
    {
        if(  listen( listening, 10 ) == -1 )
        {
            printf( "ERROR,Listen error\n" );
        }

        printf( "servertest2\n" );
        accepted = accept( listening,( struct sockaddr* )NULL, NULL );
        memset( sendbuff, '\0', sizeof( sendbuff ) );
        sprintf( sendbuff, "Server Connection Succesful" );
        send( accepted, sendbuff, strlen( sendbuff ), 0 );
        pthread_t talk_to_client;
        if( pthread_create( &talk_to_client, 0, clientopening, 0 ) != 0 )
        {
            printf( "error" );    
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I have changed port number to see if that does anything,but get the same result. arg[1] is the hostname that I convert to the IP address. What could be the reason for the timeout?

Comment: Your server seems to not do a lot of error checking. And why do you call `listen` multiple times? And why the thread? When creating an [mcve] don't complicate things, make it simple and as minimal as possible.

Comment: @Devs1575 Check this [DEMO](https://pastebin.com/raw/CDutkszq)

Comment: Using the character `'0'` here `memset( &serv_addr, '0', sizeof( serv_addr ) );` does not make any sense. Use `0`.

Comment: when asking a run time question, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can duplicate the problem, and therefore can help you debug it.  Amongst other problems with the posted code, the `#include` statements for the needed header files are missing.  Do you expect us to guess as to which header files your code is including?

Comment: regarding: `int main( int argc, char** argv )` When the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, then to avoid the related compiler 'unused parameter' messages, use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `printf("error\n");`  when a error message is output, it should be to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When the error indication comes from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Calling `perror( "my error message" );` correctly performs all the above

Comment: regarding: ``void* listenforclients_thread( void* arg )
{`  To avoid the compiler outputting a warning message about an unused parameter, the next line should be: `(void)arg;`

Comment: OT: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  I.E. 1024, 1025, 9345.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: when calling `socket()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: OT:  in C, a `socket` is defined to have `sock_t` type, not an `int` type.  Currently, the `sock_t` is an alias of `int`, but you cannot depend on that condition being true

Comment: regarding: `pthread_join(listenforclients,NULL);`  this statement should not be executed if the call to `pthread_create()` failed.  So the statement after the error message being output about `pthread_create()` having failed should be: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note: both `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are found in the header file: `stdlib.h`

Comment: OT: this: `char buffer[1025];` and this `memset( buffer,'\0', sizeof buffer ) );` can be replaced with: `char buffer[ 1025] = { '\0' };`

Comment: regarding: `bind( listening, ( struct sockaddr* )&serv_addr,  sizeof( serv_addr ) );`  Always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful (==0)  If not successful.  call: `perror( "bind failed" );` then `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `if( listen( listening, 10 ) == -1 )
    {
        printf("ERROR:listen errpr\n");
        return NULL;
    }`   It should be: `if( listen( listening, 10 ) == -1 )
    {
        perror("ERROR:listen errpr\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

Comment: regarding: `f(  listen( listening, 10 ) == -1 )
        {
            printf( "ERROR,Listen error\n" );
        }`  This second call to `listen()` should be completely removed

Comment: regarding: `sock_t accepted = accept( listening,( struct sockaddr* )NULL, NULL );`  Always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful I.E. `accepted` >0

Comment: when calling `send()` or `recv()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the function: `clientopening()` is missing

Comment: when ever the function: `pthread_create()` is successful, then (eventually) there needs to be call to: `pthread_join()` for the same `pthread_t` value

Comment: in general, when creating a thread for each client connection, it is much better/faster to have already created a 'thread pool' and just grab an entry from the pool for each client connection

Comment: regarding: `char *hostname = argv[1];`   Before accessing anything beyond `argv[0]`, always check `argc` to assure the command line parameter was actually entered

Comment: regarding: `recv( newsocket, getbuff, sizeof( getbuff ), 0 );
    printf( "test%s\n",getbuff );`  the function: `recv()` will not NUL terminate the input buffer (getbuf)  so the code must check the returned value from `recv()` to 1) assure the operation was successful (>0) and 2) if successful, then NUL terminate the input buffer via: `getbuf[ value returned from recv ] = '\0';`

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I was able to figure it out. I was copying the address in wrong way. I will definitely do more error checking in the future.